# Apache access logs show a domain name where IP addresses usually are

Tags: apache

Very rarely I will get a computer attempting to connect to my server with a domain name show-up where the IP addresses usually are. Can someone explain why this is happening and if this is something I should keep a closer eye on?

(related log snippet)
`403 - ec2-52-53-242-144.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com - - [30/Nov/2017:20:26:47 -0500] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 339 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: Check HostnameLookups (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#hostnamelookups), is it on?  Better turn if off, especially if you have  a lot of traffic on your site.  Besides that it is not a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure. How can I check that?

Comment: Depending on your version it could be in httpd.conf or in extra/httpd-default.conf.

Comment: Nothing like that is enabled from what I can tell. I usually get bots from various websites like facebook, google, etc... and they never show-up as host names. this the an extremely occurrence and I'm not sure why it occurs, but if its nothing that I need to worry about then I guess its fine as is. EDIT: I just enabled HostnameLookups and got similar results, but it was disabled when I got this connection. I find this to be a little odd that this happened with it disabled